# Visualforce to Excel: Prevent long number from being displayed in Scientific Notation

Tags: visualforce, formatting, excel

I have a Visual page which offers the capability of exporting a data table to Excel.

There is a text field called Account number. Some account numbers are more than 12 digits long. When such numbers are exported to Excel, they are shown by default in the scientific format.

> 12345678912345 becomes 1.23457E+13

Currently my code for this column is:

```
  <apex:column headerValue="Account Number">                   
            <apex:outputText value="{!mt.Account_Number__c}"/>                                     
   </apex:column>
```

I tried using different formatting options but they didn't work. Also tried using `Apex:OutputField` without success.

I tried some solutions like adding css but that did not help either.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619909/format-html-table-cell-so-that-excel-formats-as-text

I know this is Excel's default behavior with numbers with 12 digits or more. 
Any ideas as to how I can force it to display them as Strings in my Visual force page?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the field is text and not a number?

Comment: Yes the field type is text as some account numbers can be numeric or alphanumeric.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to insert html **blanks** to the start and end of the string:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Account Number">                   
    <apex:outputText value="&nbsp;{!mt.Account_Number__c}&nbsp;" escape="false"/>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Superb...I did try blank spaces but not HTML blanks..This worked perfectly my friend...thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want more fine-grained control over the number formats when they are exported to Excel, you can use a combination of a dynamic style parameter in the VForce page, and associated property in your controller.

eg. in this case I'm formatting a dynamic length text field (of numbers) as a number in Excel using 0's as the format type (ie no scientific display).

In the VForce page:

```
<td style="width:160px; line-height:13px;{!GTINCodeFormat[p]}" class="ean">{!productListByParentProductName[parentProd][p].Product__r.GTIN_pfi__c}</td>
```

(the style class is using embedded controller property based on current list element)

In controller:

```
public Map<String, String> GTINCodeFormat {get; protected set;}

if (p.Product__r.GTIN_pfi__c != null) {
s = 'vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:';
codeLen = p.Product__r.GTIN_pfi__c.length();
for (Integer i=1;i<=codeLen;i++) {
    s += '0';
}
GTINCodeFormat.put(p.Product__r.Oracle_Item_Code_pfi__c, s);
}  else {
GTINCodeFormat.put(p.Product__r.Oracle_Item_Code_pfi__c, '@');
}
```